# Statically Building python for embedding in C++

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I've been trying to include Python.h into my application, but I wanted to do it statically so it can be a standalone exe that knows how to run python on its own. I've tried using the dlls and using something like iexpress to bundle the two, however, even with that method the user needs to have Python on their system path to run it, which just ruins all the convenience. Whenever I try to build python with cmake or some other methods I've seen online, there are always just very obscure errors, and fixing them just leads to more. Anyone know how to statically build python for windows, or does someone maybe already have it built?

Comment: I have heard of something named py2exe, that may be what you're looking for. For static linking, you can take the source and modify it to link statically.

Comment: Can you just include an installer for your application that installs python along with your application?

Comment: Id rather not. Id rather just have a standalone exe